# Как правильно разобрать request.POST в Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django

Имеется Django 2.2, Python 3.7 и вот такая конструкция:

**views.py**

```
def complex_detail(request, slug):
    object = RealObject.objects.get(slug=slug)
    users = RealUser.objects.filter(department=request.user.department)

    context = {
        'object': object,
        'users': users,
    }
    template = 'objects/object_detail.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**moedls.py**

```
class RealObject(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=128, db_index=True, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField('Идентификатор', max_length=128, db_index=True, unique=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(RealUser, related_name='user_objects', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name='Менеджер')
    object_type = models.ForeignKey(ObjectType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Тип объекта')
    active = models.BooleanField('Активен', default=False)
```

**template.html**

```
  <form action="complex_detail" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <select>
    {% for user in users %}
      {% if user.active == True %}
    <option name="{{ user.last_name }}">{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</option>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
   <input type="submit" role="button" value="Назначить" name="apply">
  </form>
```

---

В шаблоне (template.html) есть не большая форма в которой присутствует выпадающий список с сотрудниками отдела и кнопка "Назначить". Задача такая: Необходимо поменять автора у объекта на того которого выбираем из списка...

Спасибо за внимание.

---

ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ

**views.py**

```
def complex_detail(request, slug):
    object = RealObject.objects.get(slug=slug)
    users = RealUser.objects.filter(department=request.user.department)
    form = ChangeAuthorObject(request.user.department, request.POST)

    if 'POST' in request.method:
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            form = ChangeAuthorObject(request.user.department)

    context = {
        'object': object,
        'users': users,
        'form': form,
    }
    template = 'objects/object_detail.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ChangeAuthorObject(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RealObject
        fields = (
            'author',
        )

        def __init__(self, department, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['author'].queryset = RealUser.objects.filter(department=department)
```

**template.html**

```
<form action="complex_detail" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form }}
           <input type="submit" role="button" value="Назначить" name="apply">
          </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых: Я не вижу атрибута `name` у поля `select`. У option должет быть атрибут `value`. Почитайте про html формы

Во-вторых: Django не для таких сложных решений. Все можно сделать куда проще. Используйте django формы, и будет вам счастье, и не надо вручную копаться в POST.

Как начнете использовать формы, код сократится до:

```
{# html #}

<form ... >
    {{ form }} 
</form>
```

```
# views.py

def view_method(request, ...):
   ...


   if 'POST' in request.method:
       form = FormClass(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           form.save() # Та-да

   else:
       form = FormClass()
   ...
```

```
# форма примерно так

class FormClass(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RealObject
        fields = ['author']
```

Это куда более гибкое решение, которое проще поддерживать и валидация уже работает

---

*UPDATE 22.07.2019*

Для выбора пользователей только из конкретного отдела передайте параметром формы отдел и переопределите queryset

```
# forms.py

class FormClass(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RealObject
        fields = ['author']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        department = kwargs.pop('department', None)
        if department:
            self.fields['author'].queryset = RealUser.objects.filter(department=department)
```

```
# views.py

def view_method(request, ...):
   ...

   if 'POST' in request.method:
       form = FormClass(request.POST, department=request.user.department)
       if form.is_valid():
           form.save() # Та-да

   else:
       form = FormClass(department=request.user.department,)
   ...
```

Comment: Все так, с формами проще, но дело в том что если использовать форму то в списке будут все пользователи и админ и неактивные и т.д. вот таким образом как у меня я получаю только тех пользователей которые живут в данном отделе. На счёт name это да... Ни туда прикрутил(( если есть способ отфильтровать пользователей в формс буду очень благодарен за подсказку как это сделать...

Comment: В __init__ переопределяете QuerySet для поля выбора пользователя

Comment: А есть какой ни будь пример? Или можешь ссылку дать на документацию?

Comment: Я уже привел пример. В нижней части ответа под разделительной чертой

Comment: Хм, теперь получаю вот такой трейбэк...
'UserDepartment' object has no attribute 'get'

Если вот от сюда
form = ChangeAuthorObject(request.user.department, request.POST)

убрать request.user.department то все начинает работать, но опять же в форме получаю всех пользователей...

Comment: обновите код вопроса

Comment: Что  именно? Формс или вьюс?

Comment: Место, на которое ругается.

Comment: Все выложил. Кстати если делать как ты посоветовал, а именно твой вьюс, то получаю трейсбэк:
local variable 'form' referenced before assignment

Comment: Это ошибка возникает при использовании переменной до ее определения. перемести ее использование ниже определения

Comment: обновил ответ для вас

Comment: В шаблон вставляю {{ form }} и получаю трейсбэк 'UserDepartment' object has no attribute 'get'. Если {{ form }} убрать, то все норм работает...

Comment: Понял в чем проблема. Обновил ответ. Ща проблема в том, что django думает, что department - это data

Comment: Трэйсбэк: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'department'

Comment: вы добавили это ? def __init__(self, *args, department=None, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            if department:
                self.fields['author'].queryset = RealUser.objects.filter(department=department)

Comment: Да конечно. Все по инструкции.

Comment: так и что мне делать? Я уже по всякому попробовал (

Comment: Обновил под 100% вариант. Если не сработает, то предлагаю разбираться в чате, что еще у вас не так

Comment: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'department' ...

Comment: Скиньте мне ссылку на репозиторий с файлами views.py и forms.py